# Bevel object doesn't work

Tags: modeling, objects, bevel, extrude, fcurves

could someone help me with the following issue?
[image]

As you can see by the screenshot above I can't extrude the path using the selected profile. Both the items are curves and I have applied Rotation&Scale.
Thanks for your help

Comment: try to rotate a bevel-object in edit mode, It seems it extruded sideways

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Cube.006 (the bevel object) in wireframe, showing where its origin is?

Comment: try to rotate your Cub.006 in edit mode by 90 degrees (try x, y z until it works)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, I rotated the profile and it worked.[image]

why is this happening?

Thanks